# wxPython -- sometimes events don't fire

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython, intermittent, objectlistview-python

I am trying to create a drag/drop system for pulling objects from one ObjectListView to another.  I bind this event:

```
self.olv["music_dir"].Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.handler.begin_music_dir_drag)
```

and then handle it like this:

```
def begin_music_dir_drag(self, event):
        self.music_dir_dragging = True
        self.music_dir_drag_target = event.GetEventObject().GetSelectedObject()
        if not self.music_dir_drag_target:
            self.music_dir_drag_target = event.GetEventObject().GetSelectedObjects()
```

Then I catch the "drop" with:

```
self.olv["music_playlist"].Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.handler.handle_playlist_stop_drag)
```

And handle it:

```
def handle_playlist_stop_drag(self, event):
        if self.music_dir_dragging:
            *** A bunch of irrelevant processing ***
            self.gui_obj.frame.olv["music_playlist"].AddObjects(new_model_objs)
        self.music_dir_dragging = False
        self.music_dir_drag_target = None
```

So, this seems to work -- most of the time.  There are times it works quickly with swift mouse movements.  Other times it only works when I slow down and click and move deliberately.  Other times it won't work at all many times in a row.  I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts?

Comment: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/draganddrop/ and http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/FileDropTarget.html

Comment: I saw those, but an OLV model object is neither a file nor just text and the custom drop seemed more verbose than me just programming the capability.  I may have to try the custom drop, however, if I can't get this way to work.

Comment: When I've used wx,droptarget in the past, I couple it with a timer.event. It isn't rocket science but it works very well.